# How can I use Astroturf with Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, astroturf

I tried using its babel plugin, but that didn't work.

I am also using craco to extend/customize Create React App, but I don't know enough Webpack to make craco work with Astroturf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make [astroturf](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/astroturf) working you should push one new rule to generated by `Create React App` webpack rules:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'astroturf/loader',
            options: { extension: '.module.scss' },
        },
    ],
}
```

With [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired), `config-overrides.js` will look like:

```
module.exports = (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'astroturf/loader',
                options: { extension: '.module.scss' },
            },
        ],
    });
    return config;
};
```

With `craco` it should be similar

**Note:** `.module.scss` should be replaced with `.module.css` in case of plain css

Answer (score 1):

I found that Anton's answer didn't work for my project - the astroturf loader overwrote the built-in loader from CRA. I've had success with this `config-overrides.js`:

```
const { override, getBabelLoader, addWebpackModuleRule } = require("customize-cra");

const addAstroturf = plugin => config => {
  const babel = getBabelLoader(config);
  babel.loader = [
    { loader: babel.loader, options: babel.options },
    { loader: 'astroturf/loader', options: { extension: '.astroturf.css' } }
  ];
  babel.options = undefined;
  return config;
};

module.exports = override(
  addWebpackModuleRule({
    test: /\.astroturf\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'astroturf/css-loader'],
  }),
  addAstroturf()
);
```

The `addAstroturf` function is a custom CRA override that extends the loader with astroturf, instead of overwriting. Additionally, I found that using astroturf meant `import './Foo.css'` no longer worked - the custom extension and webpack module rule for `astroturf.css` work to isolate astroturf from the rest of the build chain.

Here are my dependencies, in case this changes for CRA in the future:

```
"create-react-app": "^4.0.0",
"astroturf": "^0.10.5",
"customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6",
```